# doctrine:database:create raises error Undefined index: dbname

Tags: symfony

here's my problem

I'm working with Symfony2, I've generated an entity, now I'm trying to create the database, but the command "php app/console doctrine:database:create" gives me this error:

[ErrorException]
  Notice: Undefined index: dbname in C:\wamp\www\sym\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\
Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\CreateDatabaseDoctrineCommand.php line 52

I've checked on the net but couldn't find any answer, could help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you correctly set your app/config/parameters.ini file?
It should countains this:

```
;app/config/parameters.ini
[parameters]
    database_driver   = mysql
    database_host     = localhost
    database_name     = your_dbname
    database_user     = root
    database_password = password
    database_charset  = UTF8
```

Comment: Yes my parameters.ini is well configurated, yet it gives me the same error :(

Comment: It's ok that was the problem I set database_host=127.0.0.1 and the other parameters :)